# why pk_range method of Django not working?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import images

def next_img(request,pk):
    if request.method == "GET":
        images_data = images.objects.filter(pk_range=(int(pk)+1,int(pk)+8))
        return render(request,"images.html",{'image':images_data})
```

I just want to retrieve the images list objects from the given range by using their primary keys and `pk_range=(int(pk)+1,int(pk)+8)` giving below error.

```
FieldError at /images/next/8/
Cannot resolve keyword 'pk_range' into field. Choices are: id, image, name, type, user, user_id
```

Comment: its double underscore, not single `pk__range`

Comment: double underscore -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range